# RTF Source Code Questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am starting to learn to work with a moderately new package (CUDArt for [Julia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_%28programming_language%29)). The [GitHub page](https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CUDArt.jl) for this package has some examples, but overall there isn't a lot of documentation available on the package, either on GitHub or the rest of the Internet.

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903079/how-to-synchronize-with-julia-cudart/37908244#37908244) because I was genuinely uncertain as to how to accomplish something with the package. About 12 hours later, I still hadn't gotten an answer, and so I went to the GitHub page again, read the source code (which is generally pretty well organized and has some comments and documentation within it). After doing so, the answer to my question was actually pretty obvious. Namely, there was a particular function within the package that accomplished just what I wanted. As far as I can tell though, I don't think there were really any ways to ascertain such an answer without going through the source code.

Since then, I've had one or two (but not more) instances where I've tried to figure something out, haven't been able to get it, but went to the source code, and it was pretty straightforward. My initial question was genuine in that I didn't know the answer at the time I asked. And, it got at least moderately positive votes (vote totals on most Julia questions aren't that high in general). Is it appropriate to post and then answer my own question in future instances like this?

Comment: Well, if it's going to be useful to future readers, focused, not calling for opinions, and has a definite answer... By all means, go for it! In regards to the linked question though, pieces of the wording (_"best practice"_, _"best way"_) are light calls for opinions which you may want to edit.

Comment: The [julia-lang] tag is the healthiest language tag at SO bar none, extraordinary answer rate at 82.6%, very enthusiastic voting with close to 4 per answer.  Very strong community.  Beware of the dark side of Q+A like this, the proper place for language documentation [is here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/release-0.4/doc/index.rst).  Anybody can contribute.  It gets to be pretty difficult to improve a language when outdated practices and advice are scattershot across forums and Q+A sites like SO.  Have you considered a blog?

Comment: Would there be some kind of psychological barrier for people to *not* look in the source of open source projects? I was able to answer a couple of questions by doing exactly that.

Comment: @RadLexus Yes, there is one. It's called laziness. ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure it is explicitly laziness, I think very often it is a matter of feeling somewhat intimidated by the idea of digging through source code. I think for a professional coder it can seem an obvious answer to go and read the source. But for us lesser mortals there is a significant psychological barrier to poking around in those Github pages.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with posting a question that you already know answer for and then the answer.  It's explicitly allowed.  You can accept your own answer if you feel so inclined.  Both your question and the answer will be judged by the community.  So make sure the both are good and helpful.

Comment: @RadLexus, in some code bases it can be hard to tell the different between the contract of an interface and implementation details. The contract and implementation distinction exists so that the implementation is free to change without breaking clients. (Though, as we've all experienced, some non-breaking changes actually break a ton of stuff because significant parts of the implementation leaked and were then depended upon. Back compat is fun!)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The source of the information ultimately matters little, when it comes to deciding whether the question is a good fit for SO or not (an authoritative source is always useful to support the answer).

What matters is how the information is presented, and how much you can *add*:

- if the information is easy to find
- and an answer is just copy/pasting this information (with proper attribution, of course) or just slightly reword it

then there is little to no reason to post a question/answer on Stack Overflow.

If however:

- either the information is hard to locate: ill-referenced, not found in the expected place, requires digging into the code because the documentation is absent or simply uses synonyms or an alternative description
- or the way it is presented is hard to grok, too terse, lack examples, ... and you think you can improve on that

then posting a question/answer is appropriate, because it means that future searchers will be more likely to find this work already done for them.

In fine, Stack Overflow is about *adding* to the collective knowledge of Internet; so if you can add (and duplicating is not adding), please do.

Comment: One of the reasons why CSS spec questions are so common... the various web specs are so hard to read...

Comment: "then there is little to no reason to post a question/answer on Stack Overflow" - wrong! From the [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour): "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming."

Comment: Those last two points explain why language-lawyer questions, while mostly copy-paste, are considered worthwhile and get votes. It's not hard to read the specifications, but actually following them is tricky.

Comment: @ssube: Yes, especially when the points are scattered through the document because 21.4 lists generic requirements that thus also apply to 21.4.2.1 that we are considering but oh, there is a small generic amendment in 21.4.2 that refers to the XXX rules in 3.4... :/

Answer (score 29):

**The mere fact that a question was answered by reading source code does not tell you anything about whether or not the question is a good one that should be answered and remain on SO.**

For instance, I could be struggling with a piece of code that is not working, post a question and upon reading the source code realize that I thought the library I'm using wants `,` as a separator between items in a list when in fact it wants `;`. Reading the source code was useful but really, I should have been paying more attention because the docs mention it. This kind of question is awful and should be deleted rather than answered.

On the other hand, I ran into a problem that was purely due to horrible documentation. Basically, the documentation said "if you want to foo the bar, call `foo(bar)`" when in fact there is no `foo` function anywhere and you have to call instead `performTheFoo(bar)`. The error messages produced were not particularly useful. (If you start from the presumption that the *official* documentation is correct, you can waste a lot of time. Is it really that `foo` does not exist or that there is no `foo` method that takes an argument of the same type as `bar`??? Or is it a permission problem? Or a connectivity problem? Or...) The *only* way to know was to dig past the documentation. This does not make for a great brain-teaser but people running into the same issue in the future could be saved a lot of hair-pulling by finding the answer on SO right away. Not Earth-shattering but useful nonetheless.

Comment: *"...but really, I should have been paying more attention."* This assumes that the library's expectations are clearly documented somewhere that is accessible to the typical consumer of that language/API. If not, a question about why the expected delimiter doesn't work would be perfectly suitable.

Comment: @CodyGray "This assumes that the library's expectations are clearly documented [...]." That was the intent.

Answer (score 12):

Louis posted some great notes about whether or not a question is good in the first place. That said:

> Is it appropriate to post and then answer my own question in future instances like this?

If you truly feel it's a good question, it's getting a positive reception, etc. then yes, please answer it. There's a reason that an "answer your own question" checkbox exists when posting questions.